# What pathfinding algorithm is suitable for a small grid and hard-coded points?

Tags: algorithm, path-finding, a-star

I made an A* pathfinder to see if it works with what I'm trying to do, but I don't think it is good enough.

My grid is not too big and has some hard-coded points so what I'm trying to do is check only the hard-coded points to find paths between them; for example:

```
┌──────────┐
│A        B│
├───────── │
│D        C│
└──────────┘
```

So to get from point A to point D the pathfinder function should tell you go from A --> B --> C --> D.

What pathfinding algorithm would work for this?

Comment: The question is totally unclear. What do you want to achieve?

Comment: Regular expression. Its a very powerfull language, to search text strings.

Comment: @EL3PHANTEN regex would be totally inappropriate for a **path-finding** algorithm.

Comment: No im not using Regex

Comment: Okey, maybe you should look into it. And it can be used in allmost any programming language, i think

Comment: Okey. @Blorgbeard. And sry user. I missunderstood the question

Comment: So you have a graph of hard-coded points and you already know the paths/distances between them?  What data structure is this stored in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a single query, A* is probably about as good as you can do.

For many queries, you can convert your grid to an undirected, weighted graph consisting only of the hard-coded points where directly connected points have an edge between them and the edge weight is the distance between them.

For your example, the graph would look something like:

```
   9
A --- B
      | 2
D --- C
   9
```

**To construct this graph:**

For matrices where every point can only get to very few other points directly, [breadth-first search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) from each point is probably the best option.

If any point can get to many others, an [all pairs shortest path](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johnson%27s_algorithm) algorithm or some derivation comes to mind, although there may be better ways.

**To use this graph:**

You can just run A* on it.

Assuming you store the coordinates of each point, you'd still be able to use [Manhattan distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manhattan_distance) as the heuristic (assuming you were using that before).